# Setting JVM options when configuring elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm configuring jvm options for an Elasticsearch cluster, and I wonder which jvm heap
would be best for my usecase.

The machine has 16GB memory and will be dedicated to a single node of elasticsearch.

The default value is 1GB, and I'm not familar with Java/JVM but I feel like this is too small.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows, you can type Windows + R, then `systempropertiesadvanced` , then set, for example:

`ES_JAVA_OPTS`

```
-Xms2g -Xmx2g
```

(You can increase value as you want, `2` is a number, `g` is gigabyte, `m` is megabyte)

[image]

Reference document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/advanced-configuration.html#set-jvm-options

https://www.javadevjournal.com/java/jvm-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

If ElasticSearch is installed as a Windows service then run

```
elasticsearch-service.bat manager
```

and specify memory options on Java tab of ElasticSearch service properties window:
[image]

See [documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/zip-windows.html#windows-service-manage)